# How to get Fourier transform of Fisher-Kolmogorov?

Tags: pde, fourier-transform

How can I use Fourier Transform to solve Fisher-Kolmogorov Equation in 1D?

\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(t) + u(1-u)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u(0,x) = \phi(x)
\end{equation}

with Dirichlet 
\begin{equation}
u(0,t)=0 \\
u(1,t)=0
\end{equation}

and Neumann boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
u_x(0,t)=0\\
u_x(1,t)=0
\end{equation}

Can I just do the following?

\begin{equation}
F\{u(x,t)\}=\hat{u}(k,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(x,t)e^{-ikx}dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{u}_t(k,t) = (ik)^2\hat{u}(k) + F\{u(x,y)(1-u(x,t))\} \\
u_t(x,t)=F^{-1} \{ (ik)^2\hat{u}(k) \} + u(x,y)(1-u(x,t))
\end{equation}

[This](https://gist.github.com/ilciavo/ffea558fd290a2a99b0b) is a simple Matlab implementation in 1D:

After 250 iterations using forward Euler with $\Delta t = 0.01$ , the solution looks something like [image: Fisher-Kolmogorov]

Comment: I don't understand what the plot shows. The function you are seeking, $u(x,t)$ depends also on time, but your plot only shows the $x$-dependence.

Comment: It's one frame after 250 iterations using forward Euler and $\Delta t = 0.01$

Comment: OK, but so is the shown solution correct or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be partially solved following [this](http://www.wikiwaves.org/Reaction-Diffusion_Systems) tutorial.

Given Fisher-Kolmogorov equation

\begin{equation}
u_t=u_{xx}+u(1-u)
\end{equation}

It can also be written as

\begin{equation}
u_t = u_{xx} + u\,v\\
v_t = v_{xx} - u\,v  
\end{equation}

where $v = (1-u)$

Solving the equation 
\begin{equation}
u_t = u_{xx} \\
\end{equation}

from $t$ to $\Delta t$ gives

\begin{equation}
\hat{u}_t = (ik)^2 \hat{u} \\
\tilde{u}(x,t+\Delta t) = F^{-1} \left\{e^{-k^2 \Delta t} \hat{u} \right\} 
\end{equation}

Now solving the equation

\begin{equation}
u_t = u \, v \\
\end{equation}

Using the splitting operator method we can write

\begin{equation}
u(x,t+\Delta t) = e^{-v\Delta t} \tilde{u}(x,t+\Delta t)
\end{equation}

Doing that likewise for $v$ gives the solution

[image: Solution]

[Diffusion_Reaction.m](https://gist.github.com/ilciavo/8ea235906a5e48ed11f3)

Boundary conditions still must be imposed.